# Move a textfile from a folder to another folder in Java

Tags: java, file, directory

I want to move a textfile inside folderA to folderB. But instead, the folder itself moved and not the file inside. Can someone tell me how change the code below?

```
 File source = new File("d:/files/folderA/");
 File target = new File("d:/files/folderB/");                           
                    
 boolean success = source.renameTo(new File(target, source.getName()));

 if (!success) {
            // File was not successfully moved
   }
```

Comment: You must specify the full file path, including the file name in the source and target.

Comment: @greg-449 what I want is to not declare the filename inside. Just get whatever file inside folderA then transfer it to folderB. The textfile inside changes.

Comment: Then you will need to use something like `File.listFiles` to get a list of files in the folder and choose which wants you want.